# How to draw broken arrow-type labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wonder if it is possible that with `matplotlib`, we can draw the x/y axis labels of the image. In other words, how to insert a text inside an arrow line?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, drawing with matplotlib can be achieved by overlaying arrows and text annotations. You may be able to do this in other ways.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([],[])
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)

xy1, xy2 = (0,-0.15), (1,-0.15)
txt_pos = (0.4,-0.15)
con = patches.ConnectionPatch(xy2,
                              xy1,
                              coordsA="axes fraction",
                              coordsB="axes fraction",
                              arrowstyle="<-",
                              #mutation_scale=20,
                              )
ax.add_artist(con)
ax.text(txt_pos[0], txt_pos[1], 'Turn number', 
        transform=ax.transAxes, 
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', pad=0.3,ec='w',fc='w'))

plt.show()
```

[image]